# Adding dynamic named Javascript object to an array with a for loop

Tags: javascript

Wondering if it is possible to use a loop to add dynamically named objects to an array, so I don't need to repeat the "push" on an array. Tks !!

```
  let _objA0 = { "name":"regionId", "value":"myRegion" };
  let _objA1 = { "name":"vdcId", "value":"myId" };
  let _objA2 ... _objA100
  
  let test = []
  test.push(_objA0)
  test.push(_objA1)
  ...
  test.push(_objA100)
```

Comment: do you have 100 variables of objects ?

Comment: If it's a matter of not repeating the `push` you can just do `let test = [_objA0, _objA1, ..., _objA100];` The real question though, is why you need to have these dynamically named objects to begin with.

Comment: Please show us how those objects are being created.

Comment: Tks, we have a "JSON template based"  creation flow, where the JSON contains dozens of product attributes. One of the attribute contains an array of objects with dozens of configurations. I need to populate the array with my "prepared objects", and I wish to find something decent.

Comment: I have to admit it's a lame ad hoc design in my team and I have little to do to change the design from ground up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's the right time to use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```js
let test = [];
for(let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  test.push(eval(`_objA${i}`));
}
```

Comment: Is it ever the right time to use `eval`? I mean, it's all fun and games until someone pushes an XSS exploit into one of your objects... (Not my downvote, btw)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The only dynamic variable in this eval is `i` from the loop, and it's getting the value of a variable, nothing to inject with, which is relatively safe in this case. Although it's discouraged to use it.

Comment: its also fun and games until someone decided they will write down all the variables one by one, and decide to convert it to an array.  lol, I guess its not a bad time to use eval. I will give u a up.

Answer (score 0):

You can access variables (with var keyword) by window object , try this:

```js
var _objA0 = { "name":"regionId", "value":"myRegion" };
var _objA1 = { "name":"vdcId", "value":"myId" };

let test = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    test.push(window['_objA' + i]);
}

console.log(test)
```

Comment: Well, if he can change the `let` to `var` in the generating phase, I would suggest just generate an array in the first place...

Comment: This also assumes that the code is executed in a browser context, which is not necessarily a given.